# unresolved import 'Board' with python 3.8.3 64bit

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I faced a strange problem

I have some files as bellow:

- Sudoku

  - Classes

    - Board.py
    - Solver.py
  - Tests

When using Vscode, I imported *Board* by typing:

```py
from Board import Board
```

And then tested it, it runs well.

But vscode gives me warning only in `python 3.8.3 64 bit`, but not in `python 2.7.18 64 bit`

Images:

[python 3.8.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kNGQ.png)

[python 2.7.18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzaxm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @u/LaurentTO on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/i2986i/unresolved_import_board_with_python_383_64bit/) I could fix this issue by:

1. Creating a folder named `.vscode` inside my `Sudoku` directory.
2. Create a `settings.json` file inside `.vscode`
3. Writing(in my case) this JSON code in it:

```
{
  "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./Classes"]
}
```